# How to add a line in the pdf generated pdf by `exams` using the `exams2nops`?

Tags: r, r-exams

We are generating a pdf through `exams2nops` using the items in blocks of choice, we would like to delimitate the blocks in the PDF adding a horizontal line after the last exercise of each block. Having that in mind we added a `***`, `---`, `<hr/>` however the behavior was always the same:

[image]

I would like a single line without adding the exercise number that's next in the exam:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so easy to solve this by putting the horizontal line into the exercise file. The reason is that the line is needed *after* the answerlist but the answerlist is not formatted in the exercise but by `exams2nops`.

A workaround is to tweak the definition of the `{question}` environment in the LaTeX template used by `exams2nops`. By default this is simply:

```
\newenvironment{question}{\item}{}
```

Where `\item` is executed at the beginning of the `{question}` and nothing at the end of it. Changing this by

```
\renewenvironment{question}{\item}{\hrulefill}
```

would insert a horizontal line after *every* question. If you just want it after selected questions you need to insert if/else statements for certain enumerated items. For example, for inserting the horizontal rule after the second item only, you can redefine:

```
\renewenvironment{question}{\item}{\ifnum\value{enumi}=2 {\hrulefill} \else {} \fi}
```

Thus, you get the `enumi` counter from the `{enumerate}` environment that you use and compare it with `2`. If true, you insert the horizontal line, and otherwise you do nothing.

Adding escapes for the backslashes you can pass this re-definition to `exams2nops` through the `header` argument:

```
exams2nops(c("swisscapital", "switzerland", "tstat2", "deriv2"),
  header = "\\renewenvironment{question}{\\item}{\\ifnum\\value{enumi}=2 {\\hrulefill} \\else {} \\fi}")
```

The resulting output is:

[image: exams2nops output with hrulefill tweak]

Comment: This is indeed s complex solution. The problem is that it always puts the line after the same number of items. I guess the optimum solution would be to have cloze type items in exams2nops. Is there an intention to include those in exams2nops or there's some technical difficulty?

Comment: Re: complex. It's not obvious but in the end just one line of LaTeX code. // Re: same number of items. Why is that a problem? Will the sections have a different number of items for different students? // Re: cloze items. Not planned for exams2nops. You could only combine choice items anyway - and that wouldn't provide much advantage over a sequence of choice questions (as far as I can tell) but would require a lot of adaptations in the generation, scanning, and evaluation code.

Comment: We have blocks of `schoice` questions that pertain to the same problem, e.g.:
1 - Which statistical test should you use to solve this problem?
2 - Accordingly with your choice, which is the correct pair of hypotheses?
3 - Which is the test statistic?
4 - P-value?
5 - Effect size?
6 - Decision and conclusion

This could be an example of an ANOVA one-way, for instance. However, for multiple linear regression, we do a different number of questions.

Comment: That is fine if course. But you could put a line after exercise 6 and another one after exercise 10. Why is that not a sufficient solution for your question?

Comment: if I read you correctly, the line always comes after a given number of options. Our problem is that we have blocks of nested questions. For some blocks there are 3 questions, for others 4, for others 5, etc... If the number of questions per block was always the same, then ok, your suggestion would be a sufficient solution.

Comment: But you know the order of the blocks, don't you? If you have blocks of 3, 5, and 2 exercises, then I would draw one line after enumi 3 and another line after enumi 8. Or why is that not feasible?