# Force or prevent Pagebreaks by diffrent Sections inside exams2nops

Tags: r-exams

I want to create a exam with exams2nops. My approach is to have diffrent types of Questions inside of Sections. Iam wondering, if i could force or prevent a pagebreak inside various sections (or parts) of the exam. For this approach i need to define this sections clearly and i dont have a clue how to do that.

In a other thread a while ago it was explained a little bit:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083216/r-exams-prevent-page-breaks-between-two-paragraphs-in-exams2nops), but unfortunately it dont helps me...

With the argument `exams2nops(...,header "\\renewenvironment{question}{\\item}{\\newpage}"` i can force to do a pagebreak after each question. That might be a an answer for my problem, but I don't want to waste paper unnecessarily. I tried also `/nopagebreak`, but it didnt worked. The problem is, that when it comes to a plot or an image, the question, item or plot/image cuts "in a half". That circumstance could be very confusing for the students, when they have to interpret a large output.

So i came to the conclusion that there must be an option to define sections who seperates different types of questions, esepccially questions with plots. Then i could define the `renewenvironment`-argument with this sections. Following a example of my idea:

Section 1

- Multiple Choice, only text based.
- little space needed
- no pagebreak

Section 2

- Multiple Choice with Plots.
- More space needed, because of the Interpretation of the Plots.
- pagebreak!

Section 3

- open Questions with and without plots.
- even more space needed
- definitely pagebreak!

---

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: This can be done but it's not straightforward. Have you seen this post and tried to use the same strategy with the `\ifnum` conditions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703374/how-to-add-a-line-in-the-pdf-generated-pdf-by-exams-using-the-exams2nops/65730533#65730533

Comment: Ok thank you. I tested it with this Syntax `"\\renewenvironment{question}{\\item}{\\ifnum\\value{enumi}= 3 {\\item} {\\newpage} \\else {} \\fi}")` But it doesnt work properly. Its confusing me, because in the example with the `{\\hrulefill}` it works, but only for question 3... What i want to do is to tell latex, that he have to start at question 3 and end at *n*... what iam doing wrong?

Comment: I found a solution for my problem. The additional {//item} caused the problem. Also i changed the relation ‚=‚ to ‚>‘.